# HTML+Javascript to read local file system

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, client-side

I am Java developer by birth with very limited hands on client side programming, so need help here.

I am basically looking for a way to create single page HTML/JavaScript application to read my local file system. I want to list directories and files within specific directory on my HTML page. What are the ways to achieve this.

Please note that I want to avoid server side coding or web application and stuff. Just need plain HTML and/or Javascript or any Javascript framework to do this for me. And I need it to be working primarily on chrome.

Please suggest.

Comment: You can't do that with plain script, as it would be a huge security risk.

Comment: It is not possible to access file system using client side code. You must have to write service to do the same.

Comment: its a security violation

Answer (score 0):

Though its not a good to read the files at client side lot of security and access issues may occur. Still if you want you Can read the file at client side using filereader,check the following example:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
    //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
    var files = evt.target.files; 

    if (files) {
        for (var i=0, f; f=files[i]; i++) {
              var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function(f) {
                return function(e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
            console.log(contents);
                    alert( "Got the file.n" 
                          +"name: " + f.name + "n"
                          +"type: " + f.type + "n"
                          +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
                          + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
                    ); 
                };
            })(f);

            r.readAsText(f);
        }   
    } else {
          alert("Failed to load files"); 
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please help me with listing files/folders within given folder. That's my primary task. Later I want to process the files for which I can use above code it seems.